# operable program or batch file.'phantomjs' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: php, batch-file, phantomjs

I am trying to exec phantomjs in PHP on my Windows 7 machine. The strange thing is that if I type "phantomjs --version" in command line, it will execute successfully. But if I put it into code,

```
echo exec("set PATH=%PATH%;C:\phantomjs");
echo exec("phantomjs --version 2>&1", $output);

foreach($output as $result) {
  echo $result, '<br>';
}
```

Gives the following output:

> operable program or batch file.'phantomjs' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I have checked my PATH setting, and C:\phantomjs is there.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Have you tried just doing an echo from the cmd (exec) to check if that is working?
Also have you tried basically just ("C:\phantomjs\phantomjs --version 2>&1", $output);

Comment: you mean echo %PATH% from exec? yes, I tried that. C:\phantomjs is listed there.

Comment: I had this issue when using ffmpeg, if it is the same issue then the first command isn't actually setting the path therefore wherever your php file is, is where it is trying to execute the phantomjs, just try the whole path using   somthing like '../../../phantomjs/phantomjs --version 2>&1' and remove the first exec

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @krisph , lovely!